# Синхронизация данных 1с с сайтом

Tags: modx, 1с

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос к вам, форумчане: отчего зависит скорость синхронизации данных 1с с сайтом? Если кто не в курсе, использую опцию в 1с "Обмен с сайтом". Вроде объем базы один и тот же, но, тем не менее, иногда база синхронизируется довольно быстро с сайтом, а иногда думает очень долго. Сайт построен на modx, используется специальный компонент mSklad для работы с 1с. Вчера на удивление быстро прошла синхронизация данных с 1с, а сегодня опять почему-то долго думает. С чем такие разные скорости связаны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

объем базы и данный для синхронизации совсем разные вещи в данном случае) 
почитайте про планы обмена в 1С станет немного яснее)
Вкратце объясню своими словами (может моментами не совсем прально но принцип один)- допустим вы совершили обмен с сайтом в 1.01.2014 в 1С это фиксируется. Далее все добавленные данный после последнего обмена попадают в следующий обмен) все измененные данные после  1.01.2014 тоже попадают в обмен. Поэтому у вас может база сама и не расти (кол-во записей не увеличивается) но много изменений было.

Еще такой момент 1С - система разрешает напрямую работу с базой только оператору SELECT (выборка). Операции удаления, изменения происходят только через объекты. То есть чтобы изменить 1 атрибут в модели вы сначала ее находите в базе  и загружаете в модель - далее меняете атрибут и опять запрос на изменение.

А теперь представьте с сайта зашло на синхронизацию 100 строк (100 объектов) - в нормальной языке вы через проверки, модификацию пришли бы к 1-ому запросу UPDATE  -послали его в базу и все) Но тут то 1С - она сделает как минимум 100 запросов - загрузить объект, 100 изменить данные объекта. И ето если у вас объекты не имеют ссылки на другие объекты (справочники, документы) - тут еще больше запросов.

Я бы подошел к проблеме так - в каком случае у вас база 1С является ведущей а в какой ведомой? ТО есть если на сайте товары не меняются и не добавляются - то гнать их из сайта в 1С обратно смысла нет. Если по заказам ситуация иная - то гнать из базы 1 С на сайт тоже смысла нет - меньше операций быстрее работать будет)
А трафик как приходит можете посомтреть ? может излишние данные приходят

Comment: Да спасибо за ответ, отметил как верный ответ. Что-то примерное такое я подозревал, что там творится у меня. Хотя сам разработчик компонента mSklad еще подкинул мне такую идею, что это зависит от настроек таймаута (в mSklad), когда он больше установленного, чем на сервере значения, то просто начинаются повисания 1с при синхронизации данных. При проверке такой теории причин повисания проблема не решилась все равно. Так что еще предстоит выяснить причину...

Comment: Посмотри еще, какие данные приходят, в каком формате, как сформированы.

Comment: Приходят следующие данные от 1с на сайт по товарам: начиная от их названия и прочих реквизитов (цена, количество, производитель и т.д). Обратная связь тоже есть, заказы, сформированные на сайте, попадают в 1с в "Продажи клиентам". Все работает, но очень нестабильно, если сработает, то считаю за счастье такой момент.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: Инициатором соединения всегда выступает 1с, скрипт не может подключаться к 1с, можешь почитать по этому поводу в интернете, только 1с берет с сайта и передает данные сайту (так везде и в Битриксе, и в Modx и других системах). С сайта в 1с не перегоняются обратно номенклатура товаров, только операции заказы какие сделаны на сайте (и что именно заказал человек), эти данные должны поступать в бухгалтерию, так как это важный аспект полноценной работы сайта при поддержке 1с. Это не менее важно, чем экспорт номенклатуры товаров с 1с на сайт.

Comment: Так и я об этом говорю. )  
Только смотри - как приходит номенклатура из заказа в виде Наименования или в виде id  в базе на сайте или в виде ссылки в базе 1С?

Comment: Номенклатура приходит полная по товару, начиная от уникального номера и заканчивая второстепенными реквизитами, все это сразу загоняется в базу Modx. Самое интересное, что структура номенклатуры товаров (сами каталоги и его подкатегории) формируются на сайте очень быстро, работа не катит только с самими товарами, которые включены в эти каталоги. 1с мучительно думает над чем-то, пытается осилить проблему эту. Жаль, что поставили в хэшкоде ограничение по комментам, это существенно ограничивает возможность выяснить суть проблемы, когда диалог сводится к четырем сообщениям только от каждого юзера

Comment: Обнови вопрос, если появляется какая-либо конкретика - где именно затупы. )